# Is it possible to add HTML buttons in send an email(V2) of Power automate. I want to create 3 buttons which has links to 3 different sharepoint sites

Tags: power-automate, send-email, html5

I am trying to trigger an email via Power Automate which includes 3 buttons and few other information. when the recipient receives this email, he has 3 buttons which on click takes him to different sharepoint site. Is it possible to achieve this using html in 'send an email(v2)' of power automate.[image]

Comment: Are you looking links (<a>) created with pure HTML and CSS that look like button or are you specifically looking of a button like **<input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="msg()">**, which requires a script to fire the click event. I don't think it's permitted in emails for security reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can make html button () works in emails. However, you can create links () with pure CSS and  elements that would looks like button.

See sample of HTML used in [Send an email (V2)] MS flow

```
<p><br>
<br>
This is a <strong>Test</strong> email containing links  looking like html buttons<br>
<br>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
      <td>
          <table cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
              <tr>
                  <td style="border-radius: 5px;" bgcolor="#1281ee">
                      <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" style="padding: 8px 12px; font-size: 14px; color: #ffffff;text-decoration: none;font-weight:bold;display: inline-block;">LTA                            
                      </a>
                  </td>

    <td style="border-radius: 5px;" bgcolor="#1281ee">
                      <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" style="padding: 8px 12px; font-size: 14px; color: #ffffff;text-decoration: none;font-weight:bold;display: inline-block;">SMT                              
                      </a>
                  </td>

<td style="border-radius: 5px;" bgcolor="#1281ee">
                      <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" style="padding: 8px 12px; font-size: 14px; color: #ffffff;text-decoration: none;font-weight:bold;display: inline-block;">SOP                              
                      </a>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </table>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>
</p>
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, Rahman, you're great! :)

Comment: I have one more requirement - Is it possible to add input textbox in send an email(V2) of Power automate. For example, the user can add his comment and then click on SOP/SMT/LTA and then the comment gets saved in the sharepoint list.

Comment: The question is how are you planning to save the comments to SharePoint? Clicking on the link (button), users navigate to the URL location, but I don't think comments can be transferred to the URL location and then to save to SharePoint.

Comment: I am not sure how can the comments be saved in one of the columns in the sharepoint list. Also, is it possible to track who clicks on the link(button), the person's email id? Actually, now the problem is the mail is triggered through power automate with links and it has people in To list and CC list. the problem is we want only the person in 'to' list to take a decision and click on the link but here even the people in 'cc' are able to respond. :(

Comment: The easiest is to send two separate emails from PowerAutomate, one with link button for the **TO** recipients and the other without the links for  the **CC** recipients. Other contents in the email would be the same

Comment: Thanks this is amazing :)